# For image quantization, is it necessary to sample image?

Tags: sampling, image-processing, quantization

When we want to quantize an image, is it necessary to do sampling? When we know that image is a discrete signal, is it necessary to find the best samples with Nyquist rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantization of a continuous signal is the process of representing an infinite set of input values, $x(t)$, that fall into an interval $I_k=[a_k,b_k]$, with a single level $y_k(t)$, the output, that represents all the inputs to that interval with some optimality criterion.

You can quantize an analog signal without sampling it. (however don't mix this with **binarization** of its amplitude). To do so, you can pass the analog signal from a set of reference thresholders, whose output will be constant as long as the input signal remains in a given interval. Binarization is not necessary if you do not want to convert this into a digital signal.